# Is there a way to access and modify an Eclipse plug-in's source code at runtime?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing an Eclipse plug-in which has a UI. What I need is to be able to access at runtime the code of the plugin (load some class names from the plugin to construct a dropdown list in the UI) and also to be able to generate a class in the plug-in's source code, the same way, at runtime.

Is there any possible way to do this?

In order to access the code, I tried the following:

```
    IWorkspace thisWorkspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    IWorkspaceRoot thisWorkspacesRoot = thisWorkspace.getRoot();
    IProject thisProject = thisWorkspacesRoot.getProject("MyPluginsNameHere");
    IJavaProject thisJavaProject = JavaCore.create(thisProject);
```

and then I parse this IJavaProject and get the classes.

The problem is that the variable **thisWorkspace** is loaded with the runtime eclipse application's workspace, instead of the workspace of the plugin.

This problem was discussed here: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/105604/

The given solution was:

> I found the trick for workspace location. Here is my code:
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().ge tRoot().getLocation()
>
> When i run this for testing via "Launc an Eclipse Application" or "Run
>   Eclipse Application" buttons, it returns this location:
>   workspace: C:/Documents and Settings/rbt/My
>   Documents/runtime-EclipseApplication
>
> But when i export it as a "Deployable Plug-in" (File->Export->Deployable
>   plug-ins and fragments), restart Eclipse and execute it as deployable
>   plugin. This time, it returns this location:
>   C:/Documents and Settings/rbt/My Documents/workspace

This cannot be applied to my plugin, as I am dependent on another plug-in which cannot be exported as a Deployable Plug-in.

Is there any other way to do this, and run the plugin as an Eclipse application?

Comment: Plugins are not part of the workspace, they are not in projects, and don't normally contain any source code. If you want to use IProject and IJavaProject you would have to create a Java project in the current workspace.

Comment: Problem was solved by importing the plugin's project in the runtime workspace. Thank you!